# What is the proper way to deal with (score) dispersion in sentiment analysis on different topics in relation

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I'm analyzing sentiment on a social network. Based on different **topics in relation** as an input. How can we deal with dispersion of individual topics scores?

For example: we are trying to score sentiment on a theme which is an event that includes different keywords, let's say the *theme is Innovation week* with the following topics (keywords or synonyms):

`Innovation week = {"innovation week", "data solution", "emerging technologies", "august 30"...}.`

What if standard deviation of scores is so big. 
Do we question:

- The sentiment analysis algorithm itself?
- Our input keywords?
- Or we just take results as are? as they represent different views of people on different levels of granularity constituting a theme? The purpose finally is to have a general insight on a theme.

I think the question is simple although this is a concern of any sentiment analysis study in social networks.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about a programming problem, which makes it off-topic for StackOverflow. You would probably have a greater chance at getting a useful answer, if you ask on the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is both the algorithm and the input keywords as they are dependent on each other.
Given the right input the dispersion would increse in any algorithm and given the wrong algorithm the same will happen for any input.

Usually in this cases you should revise the algorithm as this is the case in most situations.

You can also read this in order to understand it better:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/omsa/omsa-published.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure in your algorithm, maybe use the NLTK Vader Sentimenter to check the results. But it could be that the answers are so different that the standard deviation scores are so big.

Do you have test data to test your algorithm? If not you should have them anyhow to measure the standard measurements of algorithm.

[Standard Measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)